# replace the punctuation with whitespace

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a problem with the code and can not figure out how to move forward.

```
tweet = "I am tired! I like fruit...and milk"
clean_words = tweet.translate(None, ",.;@#?!&$")
words = clean_words.split()

print tweet
print words
```

Output:

```
['I', 'am', 'tired', 'I', 'like', 'fruitand', 'milk']
```

What I would like is to replace the punctuation with white space but do not know what function or cycle use. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 50):

It is easy to achieve by changing your "maketrans" like this:

```
import string
tweet = "I am tired! I like fruit...and milk"
translator = string.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' '*len(string.punctuation)) #map punctuation to space
print(tweet.translate(translator))
```

It works on my machine running python 3.5.2 and 2.x.
Hope that it works on yours too.

Comment: Not sure for python3 but for python2.7.x change `str.maketrans(...)` to `string.maketrans(...)`

Comment: for python 3 use str.maketrans and not string.maketrans

Comment: The solution with regex provided below is much faster

Answer (score 21):

Here is a regex based solution that has been tested under Python 3.5.1. I think it is both simple and succinct.

```
import re

tweet = "I am tired! I like fruit...and milk"
clean = re.sub(r"""
               [,.;@#?!&$]+  # Accept one or more copies of punctuation
               \ *           # plus zero or more copies of a space,
               """,
               " ",          # and replace it with a single space
               tweet, flags=re.VERBOSE)
print(tweet + "\n" + clean)
```

Results:

```
I am tired! I like fruit...and milk
I am tired I like fruit and milk
```

Compact version:

```
tweet = "I am tired! I like fruit...and milk"
clean = re.sub(r"[,.;@#?!&$]+\ *", " ", tweet)
print(tweet + "\n" + clean)
```

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways to approach this problem.  I have one that works, but believe it is suboptimal.  Hopefully someone who knows regex better will come along and improve the answer or offer a better one.

Your question is labeled python-3.x, but your code is python 2.x, so my code is 2.x as well. I include a version that works in 3.x.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

tweet = "I am tired! I like fruit...and milk"
# print tweet

clean_words = tweet.translate(None, ",.;@#?!&$")  # Python 2
# clean_words = tweet.translate(",.;@#?!&$")  # Python 3
print(clean_words)  # Does not handle fruit...and

regex_sub = re.sub(r"[,.;@#?!&$]+", ' ', tweet)  # + means match one or more
print(regex_sub)  # extra space between tired and I

regex_sub = re.sub(r"\s+", ' ', regex_sub)  # Replaces any number of spaces with one space
print(regex_sub)  # looks good
```

Answer (score 3):

All of these answers seem to be complicating things or not understanding regex very well. I recommend using special sequences to catch any and all punctuation you're trying to replace with spaces.

My answer is a simplification of Jonathan's leveraging Python regex **special sequences** rather than a manual list of punctuation and spaces to catch.

```py
import re

tweet = 'I am tired! I like fruit...and milk'
clean = re.sub(r'''      # Start raw string block
               \W+       # Accept one or more non-word characters
               \s*       # plus zero or more whitespace characters,
               ''',      # Close string block
               ' ',      # and replace it with a single space
               tweet,
               flags=re.VERBOSE)
print(tweet + '\n' + clean)
```

Results:

```
I am tired! I like fruit...and milk
I am tired I like fruit and milk
```

Compact version:

```py
tweet = 'I am tired! I like fruit...and milk'
clean = re.sub('\W+\s*', ' ', tweet)
print(tweet + '\n' + clean)
```

What separates my version from Jonathan's is symbols like hyphens, tildes, parentheses, brackets, etc are all caught and removed, not just the list of given punctuation, catches any non-space whitespace, like tab, newline, etc. and converts to a single space.

Jonathan's version is good if you want to remove a specific list of punctuation but not *all* punctuation, like my solution does.

If you don't want to even allow underscores in your text, you can replace the special sequence `\W` with just a simple `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`, i.e.

```py
tweet = 'I am tired! I like fruit...and milk'
clean = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*', ' ', tweet)
print(tweet + '\n' + clean)
```

---

Special sequence explanation, from [Python's documentation on regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

"The special sequences consist of `'\'` and a character from the list below."

`\W`: Matches any character which is not a word character. (A word character, `\w`, includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore.)

`\s`: For Unicode (str) patterns: Matches Unicode whitespace characters (which includes `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`, and also many other characters, for example the non-breaking spaces mandated by typography rules in many languages).

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution that uses list comprehension and `str.join`:

```py
import string

tweet = "I am tired! I like fruit...and milk"
clean_words = ''.join(' ' if c in string.punctuation else c for c in tweet)
words = clean_words.split()

print(tweet)
print(words)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're using Python 2.x you could try:

```
import string

tweet = "I am tired! I like fruit...and milk"
clean_words = tweet.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)

print clean_words
```

For Python 3.x it works:

```
import string

tweet = "I am tired! I like fruit...and milk"
transtable = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
clean_words = tweet.translate(transtable)

print(clean_words)
```

These parts of code removes all the punctuation symbols from string.

Comment: this replaces punctuation with None, resulting in one word 'fruitand'. User needs to be careful if they want to replace with space

Comment: this is not this questinon ask for, this questions need to replace puncktuations with space